# Model attributes from dropdown list not transferring

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, model, yii

I have a `resume` table that has (among other things) a `position_type_id` column that is a foreign key to the `position_type` table.

On the `resume` creation form, the options for the dropdown list for `position type` are pulled correctly from the `position_type` table, and they are set with their id's as the values for the selections. All seems to be going well.

When the form is submitted, I can verify that the values are going back to the controller in the POST variable, however they are not passed into the model with the attribute population:

`$model->attributes=$_POST['Resume'];`

Here is the `create` method on the controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Resume;

    if(isset($_POST['Resume']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Resume'];

        if($model->save())
        {
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }   
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Here is the form that loads the keys from the related model:

```
echo $form->activeDropDownList(
    $model,
    'position_type_id',
    CHtml::listData(PositionType::model()->findAll(),'id','name')
);
```

`position_type_id` is the key on the resume model that carries the foreign key to the PositionType model. It is spelled the same on the form and on the resume model. The relation on the model is: `'positionType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PositionType', 'position_type_id'),`

I suppose I could get each value out of the POST array and set them manually, but it seems like this should 'just work'. The values on the `$model` after the attributes get set are there for the manually entered fields, and blank for all fields that come from a generated dropdown list.

Here is what actually gets generated:

```
<select name="Resume[position_type_id]" id="Resume_position_type_id">
    <option value="1">English Teacher</option>
    <option value="2">School Administrator</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is the form posting via `POST`? Also is `position_type_id` set as safe for mass assignment in your model's `rules()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong but for me the massive assignment is not working. In yii an attribute needs to be declared as safe if we need to perform massive assignment on it.

So In your model `Resume` do you have the following rule:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        //the other rules ...
        array('position_type_id, others_attributes', 'safe'),
        //the rule above indicate the attributes that can be massively assigned
    );
}
```

[A link to the wiki about the 'safe' validation rule](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/)